# Product of linear factors polynomial expansion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Not sure what this is called but if you have 
$(x-a_1)(x-a_2)$ and expand it and then $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)$ and then for 4 linear factors etc you start to see a pattern and it is known as the expansion of some guy whose name begins with V. The coefficients are sums of products of permutations of the roots $a_i$. What is it called?

Comment: V for Vendeta...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) that gives the coefficients of a polynomial of degree $n$ that has as roots the numbers $\{a_i: i=1 \cdots n\}$.